# Calculando um quadrado mágico

Tags: python, matriz

Estou a tentar fazer um quadrado mágico:

- Um quadrado mágico é aquele dividido em linhas e colunas, com um número em cada posição e no qual a soma das linhas, colunas e diagonais é a mesma.
- Exemplo (3x3 - nº de 1 ate 9):

  ```
  8   3   4 

  1   5   9 

  6   7   2
  ```

Tentei usar uma matriz 3x3 e um vetor com 9 indíces.

```
import random
                #j(coluna)
matriz = [[1, 2, 3],#i(linha)
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]]
res = False
#DEFINIR UMA FUNÇÃO PARA CALCULAR AS SOMAS DE TODOS OS LADOS
def magicsquare():
    if matriz[0][0] + matriz[1][0] + matriz[2][0] == matriz[0][1] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[2][1] == matriz[0][2] + matriz[1][2] + matriz[2][2] == matriz[0][0] + matriz[0][1] + matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][0] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[1][2] == matriz[2][0] + matriz[2][1] + matriz[2][2] == matriz[0][0] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[2][2] == matriz[0][2] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[2][0]:
        return res == True
    else:
        return res == False

#DEFINIR UM LOOP PARA GERAR Nº ALEAT. ATÉ ENCONTRAR OS QUE SATIZFAZEM
#AS CONDIÇÕES DE UM QUADRADO MÁGICO
seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
while res == False:
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            z = random.choice(seq)
            matriz[i][j] = z
            x = seq.index(z)
            seq[x] = []
    magicsquare()
print (matriz)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
res = False
def magicsquare():
    if vetor[0] + vetor[1] + vetor[2] == vetor[3] + vetor[4] + vetor[5] == vetor[6] + vetor[7] + vetor[8] == vetor[0] + vetor[3] + vetor[6] == vetor[1] + vetor[4] + vetor[7] == vetor[2] + vetor[5] + vetor[8] == vetor[0] + vetor[4] + vetor[8] == vetor[2] + vetor[4] + vetor[6]:
        return res == True
    else:
        return res == False
#        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
vetor = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
if res == False:
    for i in range(8):
        w = random.choice(seq)
        #Repor o valor w(1 a 9) no index i(0 a 8). Sem usar valores e indexes repetidos
        vetor.insert(i, w)
        #Eliminar os valores já utilizados
        x = seq.index(w)
        seq[x] =[]
    magicsquare()
print (vetor)
```

O resultado é sempre: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

## **Alguém me pode ajudar a construir um quadrado mágico?**

*Usando Python 3.5.0*

Comment: Tendo este código, como ele funciona? Como eu faria pra simular a criação de um quadrado mágico? Além disso, este código possui algum problema?

Comment: Tem certeza que o código que você está usando é o mesmo que você postou aqui? Testei a primeira parte do código acima e obtive `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`. Além disso, vejo que você nunca está atribuindo o `res`, só comparando-o com outras variáveis, de modo que `while res == False:` vai entrar num loop infinito.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Vou responder baseado na sua primeira tentativa, com matriz, pois a lógica é mais simples

Em primeiro lugar, sua lógica para verificar se uma matriz satisfaz ou não a condição do quadrado mágico está correta. O problema dessa função é que ela está retornando o resultado inverso, e fazendo-o de forma obscura. Eu sugiro - especialmente se você for iniciante na programação - evitar atribuir um valor e usá-lo ao mesmo tempo, pois isso é uma fonte de erros em potencial.

Além disso, há um detalhe extra: você espera que a função `magicsquare` afete a variável `res` definida fora dela. Para garantir isso, é melhor declará-la como `global`, de modo que a função não crie uma nova cópia da mesma (não sei exatamente qual é a regra, mas tive esse problema aqui).

```
def magicsquare():
    global res
    if matriz[0][0] + matriz[1][0] + matriz[2][0] == matriz[0][1] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[2][1] == matriz[0][2] + matriz[1][2] + matriz[2][2] == matriz[0][0] + matriz[0][1] + matriz[0][2] == matriz[1][0] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[1][2] == matriz[2][0] + matriz[2][1] + matriz[2][2] == matriz[0][0] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[2][2] == matriz[0][2] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[2][0]:
        res = True  # Primeiro atribui...
    else:
        res = False # Primeiro atribui...
    return res # ...depois usa
```

Segundo, você está tentando "apagar" os valores já sorteados do conjunto `seq`, de modo que eles não sejam sorteados de novo. O problema é que você está fazendo isso simplesmente atribuindo um novo valor pra ele:

```
seq[x] = []
```

O que não só não impede que ele seja sorteado de novo como também introduz uma nova possibilidade: a de ter `[]` como elemento do seu quadrado mágico! E o pior é o seguinte: se a primeira tentativa não for válida, ele nunca vai acertar de novo, pois o valor foi apagado e não foi restaurado.

Uma forma correta de fazer seria removendo de fato o elemento do conjunto (de modo que ele não possa ser sorteado de novo) e - no início do novo loop - restaurando seu conjunto ao estado inicial de modo que ele possa tentar de novo:

```
while res == False:
    seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # Dentro do while, não fora
    for i in range(3): # 3, não 2 (0,1,2)
        for j in range(3):
            z = random.choice(seq)
            matriz[i][j] = z
            x = seq.index(z)
            seq = seq[:x] + seq[x+1:] # Remove o elemento x do conjunto
    magicsquare()
```

[Exemplo funcionando no ideone](https://ideone.com/VCvIPr)